# Get value from JSON file in Swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

I have a JSON file which i converted to a NSDictionary object. My question is how do i get one single value out from this object? I make a httppost to my webside and then i get an JSON array back with to values "success" and "userId" i want to check on the success if it is true or false.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func HttpBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    PostToServer()
    HttpPost()
}

func PostToServer()
{
    println("Button Presed")
}

func HttpPost()
{
    var postString = "email=joakim@and.dk&password=123456"

    //Declare URL
    var url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://95.85.53.176/nhi/api/app/login")
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    //Declare which HTTPMethod
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    //POST data
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response =\(response)")

        var responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding:    NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println("responseString =\(responseString)")


        var error: NSError?

        var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

        println(myJSON)
    }



    task.resume()


}

}
```

output

```
responseString =Optional({"success":true,"userId":"62"})
Optional({
success = 1;
userId = 62;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access using its key value like

```
var success = myJSON["success"]!.intValue
var userId = myJSON["userId"]!.intValue

if(success == 1) //if true
{
  //Do something   
}
```

Same with `userId`

Comment: How do i get the access_token value? @FrequencyMatched
success = 1;
    token =     {
        "access_token" = m2qocunKEJXGOKWDp4n965yHhFouOyCAtfvS0b34;
        "expires_in" = 604800;
        "refresh_token" = wF0c0A7p8gh6GMXrPpSeHVfBalxTmR3iB4KRVBx2;
        "token_type" = Bearer;
    };
    userId = 61;

Comment: `var accessToken = myJSON["token"]["access_token"]!.stringValue`

Comment: It gives me an error - "Value of optional type 'AnyObject?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use "!" or '?'? 
@FrequencyMatched

Comment: Try removing `!`. Xcode will show something if needed

Comment: It shows that i need to add "!" - and when i click the suggestion it gives me that error.

Comment: Did you also try with `?` Is is showing the same error?

Comment: but when i just pull out token var accessToken = myJSON["token"]!.stringValue and print it out it shows me nil